# App serice deployed in app service environment shows DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error

Tags: azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have been working on creating an app service environment and deploy an app service in it. I followed all the steps stated in the documentation to create the environment but when I try to browse the app service am getting

This site can not be reached.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I googled the issue and tried almost all suggested solutions but no luck. Please help?

﻿﻿

Comment: Which document did you refer to?

Comment: Thank you @JasonPan for replying and sorry for late response. To answer your question, I read the Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/creation) and other related documents with the one linked.